# There is connected why it hint no such connection in the nmtui?

Tags: centos, networkmanager

In my VM, I use the `nmcli` check status:

```
[root@localhost network-scripts]# nmcli dev  status 
DEVICE       TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION  
virbr0       bridge    connected     virbr0      
eno16777736  ethernet  connected     eno16777736 
virbr0-nic   ethernet  disconnected  --          
lo           loopback  unmanaged     --
```

You see the `eno16777736` is connected, but why I use the below command there comes the error:

```
nmtui edit ifcfg-eno16777736
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the connection `ifcfg-eno16777736` does not exist - as nmcli tells you, the connection is called `eno16777736`.

So do the following:

```
nmtui edit eno16777736
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply running `nmtui-edit` shows a menu with the available entries you can pick up from.